# How to check the number for strikes have I received?

Tags: android, google-play

2 years ago, I have received 2 email from google in the same day ( check below ). How many violations/strikes does my account need now to get suspended indefinitely ?

> This is a notification that your application submission, xxx,
>   for package ID com.xxx.xxx.xxx, has been rejected. If
>   this submission was an update to an existing app, the version
>   published prior to this update is still available on Google Play.
>
> Please address the issue described below, then submit an update with
>   your changes.
>
> REASON FOR REJECTION:Violation of the Google Play content rating
>   policy.
>
> These guidelines apply to all content in your app, including user
>   generated content, in-app products, and advertisements.
>
> After a regular review, we’ve determined that your app has an
>   inaccurate content rating. Please retake the content rating
>   questionnaire for your app and resubmit your app for publishing.
>
> All submission rejections are tracked. Repeated rejections due to
>   policy violations will result in app suspension, at which point this
>   app will count as a strike against the good standing of your developer
>   account and no longer be available on Google Play.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can submit
>   an appeal on the Google Play Help Center.
>
> The Google Play Team
>
> We’re always looking for ways to improve. Please share your feedback
>   on Play policy notification emails by completing this brief survey.

---

> This is a notification that your application, xxx,
>   with package ID com.xxx.xxx.xxx, has been
>   suspended from the Google Play Store.
>
> REASON FOR SUSPENSION:Violation of the impersonation or deceptive
>   behavior provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the
>   impersonation policy help article for more information.
>
> If you are authorized to publish on behalf of the original content or
>   brand owner, please contact us via the Google Play Help Center and
>   attach verifiable and accepted proof of permission.
>
> This particular app has been disabled as a policy strike. If your
>   developer account is still in good standing, you may revise and upload
>   a policy compliant version of this application as a new package name.
>
> This notification also serves as notice for other apps in your
>   catalog. You can avoid further app suspensions by immediately ensuring
>   that no other apps in your catalog are in violation of (but not
>   limited to) the above policy. Please also ensure your apps’ compliance
>   with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Content Policy.
>
> All violations are tracked. Additional suspensions of any nature may
>   result in the termination of your developer account, and investigation
>   and possible termination of related Google accounts. If your account
>   is terminated, payments will cease and Google may recover the proceeds
>   of any past sales and/or the cost of any associated fees (such as
>   chargebacks and transaction fees) from you.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can visit
>   this Google Play Help Center article.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a suspension counts as a strike on your account. Right now you have one suspension. If you get two more suspension your account will be terminated.